# c# linq xml attribute doesn't exist

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to read an xml file and get attribute but sometime this attribute doesn't exist.

When it doesn't exist, I get this error :

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.String]]

And :

> Critical Error : System.NullReferenceException:....

My code :

```
string url = @"http://vigilance.meteofrance.com/data/NXFR33_LFPW_.xml";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
var selectedBook = from r in doc.Descendants("DV")
                          .Where(r => (string)r.Attribute("dep").Value == Departement)
                           select new
                           {
                               Color = r.Attribute("coul").Value,
                               Risque = (string) r.Element("risque").Attribute("val").Value,
                           };
```

And the XML looks like this:

```
<DV dep="02" coul="1"/>
<DV dep="03" coul="3">
    <risque val="6"/>
</DV>
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that some `DV` elements don't have a  child `risque` element, so in this part of your query:

```
Risque = (string) r.Element("risque").Attribute("val").Value
```

`Element` will return `null`, and you will get a null reference exception when you try to call `Attribute`.

You can fix this by making not going from sequence to single item until the end, and making use of the explicit conversions from elements and attributes to primitive types like `string`.  This way, converting from attribute to string for a null attribute will just return null.

```
Risque = (string) r.Elements("risque").Attributes("val").SingleOrDefault()
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v0Ys2m) for a working demo.

Comment: Work great thank ! Do you know how to deal with multiple Risque node ? For example <DV dep="14" coul="2"><risque val="6"/><risque val="5"/>
</DV>

Comment: @Hydro it would depend on how *you* want to deal with it. Do you want the first? Last? Highest? Lowest? Total? A list of all of them?

Comment: A list of all the risque value

Comment: @Hydro in that case, use `r.Elements("risque").Attributes("val").Select(x => x.Value).ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
            var selectedBook = doc.Descendants("DV")
                               .Where(r => (string)r.Attribute("dep") == Departement)
                               .Select(r => new {
                                   Color = r.Attribute("coul").Value,
                                   Risque = r.Element("risque") == null ? null : (string)r.Element("risque").Attribute("val").Value,
                               }).ToList();
```